# How to use argparse to collect arguments for a separate command line without --?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing Python programs that run other programs, like:

```
my-wrapper-program --foo --bar git commit --all
```

Here, foo and bar are arguments to my-wrapper-program, and `git commit --all` is the sub-command I'm interested in running.  How do I do this in argparse, without having to always specify the `--` special argument?  (The common case is the simplest one: `my-wrapper-program command`.)

(With optparse, you can use `disallow_interspersed_args=False`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/issues/detail?id=52) has some suggestions.